# How do Lorentz transformations act on position kets $|\mathbf{x}\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

The Hilbert space of one particle can be spanned by position kets $|\mathbf{x}\rangle$ or by momentum kets $|\mathbf{k}\rangle$. If we denote $|k^\mu\rangle = \sqrt{2E_{\mathbf k}}|\mathbf{k}\rangle$, then we can write the action of a Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$ by:

$$\Lambda: |k^\mu\rangle \mapsto U(\Lambda) |k^\mu\rangle  = \sqrt{2E_{\mathbf {k'}}}|\mathbf{k'}\rangle,$$

where $\Lambda k^\mu = (E_{\mathbf {k'}},\mathbf{k'})$.

Can we make a similar, straightforward definition for the action of $\Lambda$ on the position kets? My first guess would be to write something like $|x^\mu\rangle = c_t|\mathbf{x}\rangle$, where $c_t$ is a number such that $\frac{d^3\mathbf{x}}{c_t^2}$ is an invariant Lorentz measure.

Comment: The naive idea of a position representation in relativistic QFT is not well-defined. It is a subtle field called [Newton-Wigner theory](https://www.google.com/search?q=newton+wigner+theory). You cannot simply assert that the Hilbert space is spanned by some $\lvert \vec x \rangle$ since you have to properly define the position operators for that first, which is far from trivial.